# d3 sunburst incomplete transitions

Tags: d3.js, zooming, transition, sunburst-diagram

I was building on top of sunburst-zoom example (/examples/partition/partition-sunburst-zoom in d3 package), 
and noticed that sometimes transitions stop "just before" the final point.
To fix this, arcTween had to be modifyed the following way:

```
function arcTween(d) {
  var xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [d.x, d.x + d.dx]),
      yd = d3.interpolate(y.domain(), [d.y, 1]),
      yr = d3.interpolate(y.range(), [d.y ? 20 : 0, radius]);
  return function(d, i) {
    return i
        ? function(t) { return arc(d); }
        : function(t) {
            if (t>.95) tt=1; else tt=t+0.05
                x.domain(xd(tt)); y.domain(yd(tt)).range(yr(tt))
                return arc(d)}
  };
}
```

This cuts off little part of start of transition, but makes it almost certainly end in consistent state.
I experienced this issue even with original partition-sunburst-zoom, but not as much as with my data and modifications.

Does anyone know the "neat" way of fixing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured. "Neat way" would be the following:

```
function arcTween(d) {
  var xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [d.x, d.x + d.dx]),
    yd = d3.interpolate(y.domain(), [d.y, 1]),
    yr = d3.interpolate(y.range(), [d.y ? 20 : 0, radius]);
  return function(d, i) {
    return i
      ? function(t) { if (t==1) {x.domain(xd(1)); y.domain(yd(1)).range(yr(1));} 
                      return arc(d); }
      : function(t) { x.domain(xd(t)); y.domain(yd(t)).range(yr(t)); 
                      return arc(d); };
  };
}
```